# How i can to delete all after last word no.x?

Tags: notepad++, editplus

How i can to delete all after last word no.4?

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word6 word7 word8 word9
word10 word11 word12 word13 word14
```

So i want to remove word5 and word14

Comment: hello, may i know what is the programming language you use?

Comment: notepad++ or editplus

Comment: PHP? javascript?

Comment: Just from a simple txt

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:\S+\h+){4}\K.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?:           # start non capture group
    \S+         # 1 or more non space character
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal space
  ){4}          # end group, must appear 4 times
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 
word6 word7 word8 word9
word10 word11 word12 word13
```

## Before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using next pattern for replacement

**Search**

```
([\w]+ [\w]+ [\w]+ [\w]+).+$
```

**Replace**

```
\1
```

[Recorded screencast](http://recordit.co/MXe88VbAHn)

Via search we select first four words and put them into a group. All others symbols till the end of the line are not affected

Via replace we put matched symbols instead of the whole line

Comment: @JeekZ you can accept my answer if no one else proposes a better answer. I'll appreciate it.